# Problems with C structs and int variables

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "struct.h"

#define NUM 3

struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};



int main(void)
{
    struct Student s_array[NUM];

    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("name: ");
        scanf("%s",s_array[i].name);

        printf("age: ");
        scanf("%i",s_array[i].age);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("%s is %i years old",s_array[i].name,s_array[i].age);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what's the problem I declared an array of structs of type student and used a for loop to initialise their fields, but when I type in the age it gives me segmentation fault. why is that??

struct.c:17:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d",s_array[i].age);

Comment: `scanf("%i",s_array[i].age);` --> `scanf("%i", &s_array[i].age);`

Comment: you want `scanf("%i",&s_array[i].age);`

Comment: oh my god, I feel like an idiot, it's true scanf needs the address..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int in the struct is an int, not a pointer to an int. Arrays can be assigned directly to pointers, but on other types, you need to apply the addressof (&) operator. Instead of saying "s_array[i].age", say "&(s_array[i].age)".

Answer (score 1):

I worked out this code for you

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
#define NUM 3
struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Student s_array[NUM];
    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("name: ");
        scanf("%s",&s_array[i].name);

        printf("age: ");
        scanf("%d",&s_array[i].age);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("%s is %d years old",s_array[i].name,s_array[i].age);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
//#include "struct.h>
 #define NUM 3
  struct Student
 {
 char name[20];
 int age;
};
int main(void)
{
struct Student s_array[NUM];
for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
{
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s",&s_array[i].name);
    printf("age: ");
    scanf("%d",&s_array[i].age);//You sud use "&"operator to take input 
}
for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
{
    printf("%s is %d years old",s_array[i].name,s_array[i].age);

}
return 0;
}
```